# Internet Authentication Service (IAS) for Mac OS X does not work on macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, internet, microsoft, authentication

I need to connect my MacBook Pro with macOS Sierra to my company using IAS for Mac OS X. If I double-click the icon of IAS for Mac OS X (made in the year 2008) it is denied due to incompatibility (between IAS for Mac OS X and macOS Sierra).

Is there an IAS for macOS Sierra?

Or is there any way to allow the installation of IAS for Mac OS X on macOS Sierra?

Comment: Do you have a link to the IAS for MacOSX software you downloaded? Maybe helps ;-)

Comment: Ask your IT team for assistance. There are much newer ways to login to a Radius server than with IAS.